# Nanofiltration Membranes design understanding

Tags: waste-water-treatment, fluid-filtration

I am doing some research to design a nanofiltration assisted water treatment plant and wanted to know some information on purchasing membranes.

I am not sure whether or not these membranes come in pressure vessels or if I have to design or procure these separately. Please provide any information on how I could tell if the membrane unit I am buying has a pressure vessel.

Example of what I have been looking at: https://www.lenntech.com/Data-sheets/Dow-Filmtec-NF-2540.pdf
In the example it seems to me that a pressure vessel here is not included and one should be bought or procured. If there are any resources you can think of for finding or designing the pressure vessel please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the membranes are available without pressure vessel (which could be a piece of pipe, probably DN125) but since the company does turn key isntallations too you could probably procure a pre-installed filtration plant (wiser than to develop one from scratch).

In your place I would ...

- search and ask if my current employer has priviosly designed/built a plant with RO or NF and see what can be recycled from the previous design work
- write down the exact specs as far as can be told (input water stream, contituents, amount, operation times ...)
- and call an application engineer of a likely supplier