# Membrane permeate prediction software

Tags: fluid-filtration

I wanted to know if there are any open software or even purchasable software available to predict the permeate quality through a nanofiltration module. I am designing a plant for my final year mechanical engineering undergraduate project and need to show what the results of my setup would be without actually building it.

Comment: Contacting the supplier may help, suggested here: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/37320/10902

Comment: Never worked with FEM myself, but I'd start writing down the models as equations to 1) confirm with my thesis supervisor that level of detail is the right one and 2) know exaclty what kind of specs I want from the modelling software.

Answer (score 3):

We lived in information era. Software here are for any problem. But all sciences software are  very hard to master: today (IMHO) more than 80% physics evaluation base on [finite-element method (FEM).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method)

FEM has a lot tensor's equations. Solvation of these equations are frequently make big load to your computer (CPU and sometimes GPU). Because of this, FEM modeling are usually makes without 3D, only in one plane. It is very easy to make mistakes when you setting boundary conditions and equations. Besides - equations (if you all will make correctly) will be solved very-very approximately.

Answering to your question: software - is, but all of these products can to solve very small objective, and very incorrect to calc. Most widely physics software - probably comsol. For example [calculation of membrane](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8oglAJZnUsg).  If you haven't 40 000$ to buy it, there are [list of FEM software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_element_software_packages). For chosing program for FEM modeling I offered my students use scientific information finder - [scholar.google.com](http://scholar.google.com). You have to step by step input request as `@software name` +  `membrane permeate` into [scholar.google.com](http://scholar.google.com) and look how many science articles was written with using of this program. After that you need to take a program which more often used by scientific community to your problem.